# Jordan decomposition on the dual Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, geometric-invariant-theory, modular-lie-algebras

$\newcommand\fg{\mathfrak g}\newcommand\gl{\mathfrak{gl}}\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $G$ be a smooth, affine algebraic group over $k$.  In everything below, I intend to work on the level of algebraic groups, not just of rational points.  I am also happy to restrict to the reductive case, and even, if it helps, to the adjoint case.  However, I am specifically interested in the case of small, positive characteristic.

There are well defined notions of a Jordan decomposition in $G$ and in the Lie algebra $\fg$ of $G$, both of which involve identifying a semisimple part and a nilpotent part that commute.

On the dual Lie algebra $\fg^*$, I don't know any reasonable notion of when two elements commute, but one can still imagine defining at least the conjugacy class of the semisimple part, as follows:  let $X^*$ be an element of $\fg^*$, and consider the coadjoint orbit $\mathscr O = \Ad^*(G)X^*$.  Are the following two statements true?

1. The closure of $\mathscr O$ contains a unique closed coadjoint orbit $\mathscr S$.
2. For every closed coadjoint orbit $\mathscr S$, there are a maximal torus $T$ in $G$ and an element $S^* \in \mathscr S$ such that $S^*$ vanishes on all root subalgebras of $T$ in $\fg$.

If one or more is not true, then is there any other way of coming up with a reasonable notion at least of the conjugacy class of the semisimple part in the Jordan decomposition?  I would prefer such a decomposition to satisfy two properties:

a.  Every $G$-invariant isomorphism $\fg^* \to \fg$ (e.g., the Killing form, when it is non-degenerate), if any, should commute with the map "taking the orbit of the semisimple part".

b. For every faithful representation $G \to \GL(V)$, we obtain $\gl(V) \cong \gl(V)^* \to \fg^*$, where the first isomorphism is *via* the trace pairing.  For every $X \in \gl(V)$, the semisimple part of $X$ is carried into the orbit of the semisimple part of its image.

Comment: For (a), a remark: the existence of such an isomorphism is a rare phenomenon, true for semisimple Lie algebras, but for some others including non-reductive such as including $\mathfrak{g}\ltimes\mathfrak{g}^*$ for arbitrary $\mathfrak{g}$ (I call it "quadrable Lie algebra"); has restrictive implications such as: dim(center)=codim(derived). It's called "metric/metrizable" Lie algebra, or "quadratic Lie algebra" depending on authors, some of these terminologies not being specific as to whether one fixes an invariant non-degenerate quadratic form, or if one assumes the existence thereof.

Comment: @YCor, I think that (a) can fail even for semisimple Lie algebras in small positive characteristic.  (For example, I think that it doesn't hold for $\operatorname{SL}_2$ in characteristic $2$, although I think one can work around the problem for all $\operatorname{SL}_n$'s.)  As I mentioned, but should probably make more emphatic, I am perfectly happy to restrict to the reductive, and even the adjoint, case.  Anyway, I agree that (a) is a weak condition, but it is one of the basic sanity checks I want to impose.

Comment: Oh, sure, I had char 0 in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few restrictions ($p \ne 2$ and $G$ has no components of special orthogonal type), my (1) and (2) are Theorem 4, parts (iv) and (ii), of [Kac and Weisfeiler - Coadjoint action of a semi-simple algebraic group and the center of the enveloping algebra in characteristic $p$](https://doi.org/10.1016/1385-7258(76)90059-7).